# Combining fields in a Couchbase Spring-Data Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, couchbase, sql++

I have a couchbase query that needs to search for a name, the object being searched stores firstName and lastName fields. My search query may be something like "Bob Smith", I have tried combining the fields in the query however this does not work ?

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter} AND LOWER(firstName) + ' ' + LOWER(lastName) LIKE $1 ")
```

Comment: Would you please mention what's happening and what you expect to happen, along with error messages? "does not work" is pretty vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment on the Java syntax, but as far as the N1QL query:

I believe you are trying to concatenate `LOWER(firstName)` and `LOWER(lastName)` with a space in between? In that case, use the [concatenate operator](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/stringops.html) of `||` instead of `+`.